# How can I get the selection direction of an NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, text, selection, nstextview

I'm trying to get the direction of the selected ranges in an `NSTextView`. In other words, whether the selected ranges change their location or length when you use `shift+leftarrow` and `shift+rightarrow`. My first though was that `selectionAffinity` represents the direction, but it only seems to apply to multi-line selections.

How can I get the direction of selected ranges?

Comment: In the bigger picture, what are you trying to do and why?

Comment: In my use case, I'm wanting to center the user's selection within the text view. In the case of a multi-line selection, I want to center whichever end of the selection is being actively moved. I'm not the OP, but an answer to the OP would answer my question as well.

Comment: @BJHomer - See my answer below, I think it'll solve your problem :)

Answer (score 7):

#### iOS

Step 1: Declare Property

```
@property (nonatomic) NSRange lastRange;
```

Step 2:  In TextView Delegate, add this:

```
- (void) textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView

    NSRange currentRange = NSMakeRange(textView.selectedRange.location, textView.selectedRange.length);

    if (currentRange.length == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Nothing selected");
        _lastRange = currentRange;
    }
    else {
        if (currentRange.location < _lastRange.location) {
            NSLog(@"Selecting LEFT");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Selecting RIGHT");
        }
    }
}
```

#### OSX

OSX with all the features requested involved a little bit more work, but here's what I came up with for a working, consistent solution.  Renaming is optional, or rather ... encouraged ...

Step 1: Subclass a NSTextView

In your `SubClass.h`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TheSelectionizer : NSTextView

@property (nonatomic) NSRange lastAnchorPoint;

@end
```

In your `SubClass.m`

```
#import "TheSelectionizer.h"

- (void)setSelectedRange:(NSRange)charRange affinity:(NSSelectionAffinity)affinity stillSelecting:(BOOL)stillSelectingFlag {

    if (charRange.length == 0) {
        _lastAnchorPoint = charRange;
    }
    [super setSelectedRange:charRange affinity:affinity stillSelecting:stillSelectingFlag];
}

@end
```

Step 2: Implement NSTextViewDelegate

```
- (NSRange) textView:(NSTextView *)textView willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRange:(NSRange)oldSelectedCharRange toCharacterRange:(NSRange)newSelectedCharRange {

    if (newSelectedCharRange.length != 0) {

        TheSelectionizer * selectionizer = (TheSelectionizer *)textView;

        int anchorStart = (int)selectionizer.lastAnchorPoint.location;
        int selectionStart = (int)newSelectedCharRange.location;
        int selectionLength = (int)newSelectedCharRange.length;

        /*
         If mouse selects left, and then a user arrows right, or the opposite, anchor point flips.
         */
        int difference = anchorStart - selectionStart;
        if (difference > 0 && difference != selectionLength) {
            if (oldSelectedCharRange.location == newSelectedCharRange.location) {
                // We were selecting left via mouse, but now we are selecting to the right via arrows
                anchorStart = selectionStart;
            }
            else {
                // We were selecting right via mouse, but now we are selecting to the left via arrows
                anchorStart = selectionStart + selectionLength;
            }
            selectionizer.lastAnchorPoint = NSMakeRange(anchorStart, 0);
        }

        // Evaluate Selection Direction
        if (anchorStart == selectionStart) {
            if (oldSelectedCharRange.length < newSelectedCharRange.length) {
                // Bigger
                NSLog(@"Will select right in overall right selection");
            }
            else {
                // Smaller
                NSLog(@"Will select left in overall right selection");
            }
        }
        else {
            if (oldSelectedCharRange.length < newSelectedCharRange.length) {
                // Bigger
                NSLog(@"Will select left in overall left selection");
            }
            else {
                // Smaller
                NSLog(@"Will select right in overall left selection");
            }
        }
    }

    return newSelectedCharRange;
}
```

I posted a project just in case someone wants to try it or wants to see it.

Full "project" available [HERE](https://github.com/LoganWright/TheSelectionizer)

Comment: It looks like the notification sent to this method includes the previous range, so the property may not even be necessary.  However, this method makes potentially-invalid assumptions when the user changes the selection with the mouse. Can you address that case?

Comment: I think this way will work better.  I moved the constant variable so it only sets if length is 0.  That way, if they select one direction and move back a little it doesn't reset.  Let me know if this works.

Comment: @BJHomer - I've never worked on OSX before, so I thought this would be a good time to check it out! I noticed your problem, and I found a way to do it.  If you subclass a `NSTextView`, you can get your desired result. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: This code works… but doesn't really answer the question. What I (and the OP, I believe) want is a way to know whether pressing shift-right will move the left or the right end of the selected range, *before* that keypress happens.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean.

Comment: @BJHomer - I added a bit to the bottom that will do the arrow thing like you're looking for I think.

Comment: Ok @BJHomer, I feel like I covered everything with this one, let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Try this: Highlight some text left-to-right, then press "shift-left". You'll see that it extends from the left. Now highlight the same text with the mouse left-to-right again, and press "shift-right". Now it extends from the right. So it's a bit more complex than you've demonstrated.

Comment: I've learned some more. Mouse selections are unanchored until you extend it with the keyboard. Then they always expand the selection and force it to be anchored. So there's really three options: No anchor, start anchored, or end anchored. I'd like a property on the text view that indicates which of those three anchor modes applies to the active selection.

Comment: Also, note that keyboard selection won't always move by 1 character; consider shift-up/down or command-shift-left/right. But I'm not sure if the distinction between mouse/keyboard selections is necessary, as long as the selection anchor can be determined.

Comment: @BJHomer - Yea, I found that last one.  Also, if you select one area, then move and select another area w/ mouse but the end of the new selection is 1 char away from the last selection's anchor, it triggers as keyboard.  I think it's close, but let me see if I can tweak it.  I'm short on time at the moment, but I'll let you know when I get a chance to work on it again.  Probably a day or two.

Comment: @BJHomer - I think I found a solution that will work. Let me know if this works! Sorry it's taken a bit, this is a tricky problem :)

Comment: This still doesn't address 100% of my concerns, but it gave me enough guidance to do what I was looking for, and I think it addresses the OP's question well enough that it merits the bounty. So, there you go!

Comment: Glad I could get you in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that NSRange yourPreviousRange is declared.

```
//Check when NSTextView changed its value
@interface delegateAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextViewDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
}

-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSRange yourRange = notification.object.selectedRange;
    if (yourRange.location == yourPreviousRange.location - 1 || yourRange.length == yourPreviousRange.length){
     //left direction  
    } else if (yourRange.location == yourPreviousRange.location || yourRange.length == yourPreviousRange.length + 1){
    //right direction
    }
    yourPreviousRange = yourRange;
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting something that "doesn't work" as an answer?

Comment: The NSRange length field is unsigned. It can never be less than zero. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSRange

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSTextViewDelegate` methods :
[-textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRange:toCharacterRange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/nstextviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextViewDelegate/textView%3awillChangeSelectionFromCharacterRange%3atoCharacterRange%3a) or [-textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges:toCharacterRanges:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/nstextviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextViewDelegate/textView%3awillChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges%3atoCharacterRanges%3a) if you want multi-selections support.

Note that if you only implements `-textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRange:toCharacterRange:` the multi-selections will be disallowed.

For example without multi-selections :

```
- (NSRange)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRange:(NSRange)oldSelectedCharRange toCharacterRange:(NSRange)newSelectedCharRange
{
    if (newSelectedCharRange.length == 0 && oldSelectedCharRange.length == 0) 
    {
        /* move the insertion point */

        if (newSelectedCharRange.location < oldSelectedCharRange.location)
            NSLog(@"insertion point move left");
        else
            NSLog(@"insertion point move right");
    }
    else if (newSelectedCharRange.length == 0 && oldSelectedCharRange.length != 0)
    {
        /* end a selection and move insertion point */

        if (newSelectedCharRange.location == oldSelectedCharRange.location)
            NSLog(@"insertion point at start from previous selection");
        else if (newSelectedCharRange.location < oldSelectedCharRange.location)
            NSLog(@"insertion point move left");
        else
            NSLog(@"insertion point move right");
    }
    else if (oldSelectedCharRange.length == 0 && newSelectedCharRange.length != 0)
    {
        /* start a selection */

        if (newSelectedCharRange.location == oldSelectedCharRange.location)
            NSLog(@"start a selection at insertion point, move right");
        else if (newSelectedCharRange.location < oldSelectedCharRange.location)
            NSLog(@"start a selection, move left");
        else
            NSLog(@"start a selection, move right");
    }
    else
    {
        if (newSelectedCharRange.location < oldSelectedCharRange.location)
            NSLog(@"selection move left");
        else
            NSLog(@"selection move right");
    }

    return newSelectedCharRange;
}
```